# Two dropdown lists in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, dropdown

I have two drop down lists in my form and want to get data from database. after getting first drop down successfully, I tried to do the same for the next one. But it gives an error.

[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I5Gt.png)

My code:

- [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Idd.png)
- [Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTy0s.png)
- [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjxv3.png)

Comment: please edit your question: instead of the image, put the code into the question. What is the error message?

Comment: is the table name really `boooks` with 3 "o":s? Please put the code in the question instead of in links to images.

Comment: Hi Michael, that was the error. Thank you so much. I've fixed it :)

Comment: Hi Vickel, next time i'll put my code into question. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your data in all foreach loop like this:

```
<?php foreach($borrower_name as $row){ ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row['borrower_name ']?>" ><?php echo $row['borrower_name '];?></option> 

<?php } ?>
```

***OR***

```
foreach($borrower_name as $row)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['borrower_name '].'">'.$row['borrower_name '].'</option>';

}
```

Comment: Actually the error was wrong spellings of table name in model

Answer (score 0):

In your modal file replace `return $query->result();` with `return $query->result_array();`